# Replace diacritic characters with "equivalent" ASCII in PHP?

Tags: php, character-encoding, diacritics

Related questions:

1. [How to replace characters in a java String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653739/how-to-replace-characters-in-a-java-string)
2. [How to replace special characters with their equivalent (such as " á " for " a") in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393887/how-to-replace-special-characters-with-their-equivalent-such-as-a-for-a)

As in the questions above, I'm looking for a reliable, robust way to reduce any unicode character to near-equivalent ASCII using PHP. I really want to avoid rolling my own look up table.

For example (stolen from 1st referenced question): `Gračišće` becomes `Gracisce`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [iconv](https://www.php.net/iconv) module can do this, more specifically, the [iconv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function:

```
$str = iconv('Windows-1252', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', "Gracišce");
echo $str;
//outputs "Gracisce"
```

The main hassle with iconv is that you just have to watch your encodings, but it's definitely the right tool for the job (I used 'Windows-1252' for the example due to limitations of the text editor I was working with  ;)  The feature of iconv that you definitely want to use is the `//TRANSLIT` flag, which tells iconv to transliterate any characters that don't have an ASCII match into the closest approximation.

Comment: Transliteration is now my word of the day.

Comment: Note, this doesn't work properly when locale category `LC_CTYPE` is set to `C` or `POSIX` (you can check what your locale is with `echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);`). All non-ascii characters will be converted to `?`s. Instead you will need to set the locale to something else first: e.g. `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8")`.

Comment: @Mike thanks for your hint. If not for you, I might have never solved that problem.

Comment: if the character is not found, a "?" replaces that special char. this should not be the most voted answer. it's misleading

Answer (score 4):

I found another solution, based on @zombat's answer.

The issue with his answer was that I was getting:

```
Notice: iconv() [function.iconv]: Wrong charset, conversion from `UTF-8' to `ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE' is not allowed in D:\www\phpcommand.php(11) : eval()'d code on line 3
```

And after removing `//IGNORE` from the function, I got:

```
Gr'a'e~a~o^O"ucisce
```

So, the `š` character was translated correctly, but the other characters weren't.

The solution that worked for me is a mix between `preg_replace` (to remove everything but [a-zA-Z0-9] - including spaces) and @zombat's solution:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/','',iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', "GráéãõÔücišce"));
```

Output:

```
GraeaoOucisce
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to create two strings - first with not wanted letters and second with letters that will replace firsts.

```
$from = 'čšć';
$to   = 'csc';
$text = 'Gračišće';

$result = str_replace(str_split($from), str_split($to), $text);
```

Comment: "I really want to avoid rolling my own look up table."

Comment: @Dolph: right now, this is the closest answer to reality. all the other answers just destroy the string or they don't function properly

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function normal_chars($string)
{
    $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $string = preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', $string);
    $string = preg_replace(array('~[^0-9a-z]~i', '~-+~'), ' ', $string);
    return trim($string);
}

Examples:

echo normal_chars('Álix----_Ãxel!?!?'); // Alix Axel
echo normal_chars('áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ'); // aeiouAEIOU
echo normal_chars('üÿÄËÏÖÜŸåÅ'); // uyAEIOUYaA
```

Based on the selected answer in this thread: [URL Friendly Username in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103797/url-friendly-username-in-php)

Comment: +1, but this only works for a subset of cases. For example, "Škoda" becomes "Scaron koda".

Answer (score 2):

You should also try:

```
transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; Lower()', "ÀÖØöøįĴőŔžǍǰǴǵǸțȞȟȤȳɃɆɏ");

//Will output
aooooijorzajggnthhzybey
```

I found this from here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php#111939